# Shell script with spinner for background process emitting extra output ("done", etc)

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm making a bunch of aliases and functions to simplify the work my team does. Just for kicks, I want to make things look really cool when functions are running by adding in a loading animation. I've taken bits and pieces from examples I've seen around, and currently have [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225179/display-spinner-while-waiting-for-some-process-to-finish#answer-565551) working. Calling it like:

```
function myFunction() {
    <function code>

    (
         <the code I run>
    ) &>/dev/null &

    spinner $!
}
```

As I said, this runs. I see the animation, which is super cool! Props to the author of this one. The issue I have is I'm getting extra output. It looks similar to:

during animation

```
<spinner>47096 �
```

after animation

```
[2]  + 45994 done       ( <the code that runs> )
```

What can I do to hide this? I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: This is happening in an interactive shell, I assume? Job control (which is what's printing your unwanted output) is off-by-default in scripts, at least in more POSIX-y shells. (zsh doesn't try to comply with the standard where its authors disagree with it, so much of what I say should be taken with a grain of salt there, but I'd be surprised if this were a difference).

Comment: Yes, it's in an interactive shell. The current function I'm working on is for adding, committing, and pushing in Git. I've had the function working fine forever, but I've just recently wanted to change the ugly output to something much more simple for my team ( who are not all familiar with working in a shell ). I'll start looking into what to do about "job control" output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out. I don't know the syntax well enough to know why this works, but wrapping the code to be run in parenthesis, and wrapping that code AND with the spinner in parenthesis seems to have done the trick. For example:

```
(
    (
        npm install &> /dev/null
    ) &
    spinner $!
)
```